# How to write the string data from user as byte array to socket

Tags: java, sockets, server

I have a class that receives messages sent by the user and prints them out on the terminal, but now I am trying to write a class that reads data from the user, converts the string data from the user into an array of bytes, and write the byte array to the socket.

I am trying to read data from the user using BufferedReader and write the byte array to the socket using OutputStream, but for some reason, the message that I am writing to the socket isn't delivered to the server.

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String newLine = r.readLine();
while (r.ready() && newLine != null) {

    // TODO: read data from the user, blocking until ready. Convert the
    //string data from the user into an array of bytes and write
    //the array of bytes to "socket".

    byte[] message = newLine.getBytes();
    OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(message);
}
```

`s` is the socket with the same server and port number as the one I am sending it to!

There are no errors when I run this, so I genuinely have no idea why this won't send the message to the socket.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Does `outputStream.write(message)` get called at all? Do you flush the stream or at least close it? On a side note: don'T use `getBytes()` as this will depend on your system's locale setting. Instead use `getBytes(Charset)` and pass the same charset in the client and server code.

Answer (score 0):

> `String newLine = r.readLine();`

Perhaps you misunderstand how java works; your confusion is logical only if you believe that this sets up a sort of alias: That everytime `newLine` is so much as touched, that it's just a shorthand for `r.readLine()`.

That is not how java works. You read a line from `r` **exactly once** in this code, at the very start, and never again. That line above means: Execute `r.readLine()` right this very moment, allow that method to put the string it gets someplace in memory, and then have `newLine` be an alias for **that string**, not for the general idea of 'pull another string off of the network buffers'.

`r.readLine()` needs to be somewhere in that loop.

More generally, don't call `.ready()`, it's not useful. Call `readLine()` only. Calling that will 'block' until data is available automatically, and will return `null` when no more data will ever come (because the connection has been closed).

Comment: To expand on the answer: `r.ready() && newLine != null` will probably always be true, even if there's no new content - this will lead to an endless loop and with the missing flush of the output stream it would look like nothing gets written. Instead it should be `(newLine = r.readLine()) != null` or something like that instead. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works!!! I got the message:)) I felt so lost and confused but now it all makes sense